# ¿Por qué no puedo actualizar el TextView desde el onCreate en esta petición a Volley de Android?

Tags: android, android-volley

Tengo una petición Volley que lanzo desde Android. El servidor recibe los datos y responde bien.

Lo que no entiendo es por qué la llamada a `launchVolley()`  y luego la llamada a `showData()` no funcionan.

#### `showData()` no muestra nada

Aquí recibo respuesta, pero `showData()` no muestra nada:

```
public class MainMasActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MasMainActivity";
    Spanned strContenido;
    ZoomTextView mTextView;
    private String finalText;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sexta);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        launchVolley();
        showData();

    }

    private void launchVolley() {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "https://www.mi.api/adduser";
        JsonObjectRequest mRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                                finalText=response.toString();
                                //showData();
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                finalText=e.getMessage();
                                //showData();
                            }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                finalText = VolleyErrorHelper.getMessage(error, getApplicationContext());
                //showData();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map getHeaders() {
                HashMap headers = new HashMap();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
                headers.put("Nombre", "Pedro");
                headers.put("Apellido", "García");
                return headers;
            }
        };

        DefaultRetryPolicy mRetryPolicy=new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                MY_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        mRequest.setRetryPolicy(mRetryPolicy);
        requestQueue.add(mRequest);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void showData() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mTextView = findViewById(R.id.tv_Zoomable);
        mTextView.setText(finalText);
    }
}
```

---

#### `showData()` muestra los datos en el textView

Este código sí funciona, llamando a `showData()` **desde dentro de `launchVolley()`**.  ¿A qué se debe esto?

Una de las cosas que me incomodan es que tengo que llamar a `showData()` desde tres partes distintas. ¿Hay alguna forma de llamar a `showData()` una sola vez?

```
public class MainMasActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MasMainActivity";
    Spanned strContenido;
    ZoomTextView mTextView;
    private String finalText;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sexta);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        launchVolley();
        //showData();

    }

    private void launchVolley() {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "https://www.mi.api/adduser";
        JsonObjectRequest mRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                                finalText=response.toString();
                                showData();
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                finalText=e.getMessage();
                                showData();
                            }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                finalText = VolleyErrorHelper.getMessage(error, getApplicationContext());
                showData();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map getHeaders() {
                HashMap headers = new HashMap();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
                headers.put("Nombre", "Pedro");
                headers.put("Apellido", "García");
                return headers;
            }
        };

        DefaultRetryPolicy mRetryPolicy=new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                MY_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        mRequest.setRetryPolicy(mRetryPolicy);
        requestQueue.add(mRequest);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void showData() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mTextView = findViewById(R.id.tv_Zoomable);
        mTextView.setText(finalText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola A.Cedano acabo de ver que el TextView es un  ZoomTextView de donde obtuviste esta clase o es una custom que realizaste?

Comment: @Elenasys sí, es un `TextView` *zoomable* personalizado para poder agrandar/achicar el texto con los dedos. Eso funciona bien, lo uso en casi toda la App.

Comment: Hola @A. Cedano probaste obtener la referencia antes de que se llame el proceso asyncrono?

Comment: Estoy probando ahora @Elenasys, me parece que antes lo tenía así y tampoco funcionaba. Ahora te cuento.

Comment: @Elenasys tampoco funciona así. Y puse esto para probar si era problema de la referencia al `textView` :  **`mTextView.setText(finalText+"Más cosas...");`** y me muestra `nullMás cosas...`. Lo que yo intuyo es que tenga algo que ver con que Volley es asíncrono, pero no entiendo muy bien el concepto ni como funciona.

Comment: @A.Cenado me parece que solo no estas obteniendo respuesta finalText=response.toString(); o si obtienes información (response) en   public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {....

Comment: @Elenasys sí sí, obtengo respuesta. Cuando llamo a `showData()` desde dentro de `launchVolley` (2º bloque de código de la pregunta), los datos se muestran. El problema es cuando, en el `onCreate()` llamo de forma consecutiva  a `launchVolley();` y luego a `showData()` (1er código de la pregunta). Aunque en `launchVolley()` seteo variables que son miembros de la clase, luego en `showData()` no son reconocidos. Eso es lo que no entiendo.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que se debe a que en el método que se llama en `onResponse()` obtienes la referencia de la vista, te sugiero obtener la referencia de la vista en `onCreate()` y posteriormente en `showData()` solo define el texto.

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sexta);
        ...
        ...
        //Obtiene referencia del TextView en el layout activity_sexta.xml
         mTextView = findViewById(R.id.tv_Zoomable);
        ...
        ...
    }



 private void showData() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        //mTextView = findViewById(R.id.tv_Zoomable);
        mTextView.setText(finalText);
    }
```